# Disable Onclick event using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<a id="disableclick" onclick="check();">DisableClick</a>

<script type="text/javascript">    
function check() {
    alert("hello");
    $("#disableclick").removeAttr('click');        
}
</script>
```

What could be the syntax to disable onclick event, the above syntax is the one which I tried

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uZc8w/670/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE THIS:

```
function check() {
    $("#disableclick").removeAttr('onclick');        
}
```

OR:

```
function check() {
        $("#disableclick").attr('onclick','');        
    }
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uZc8w/673/)

Comment: what syntax can we follow to add back again

Comment: $("#disableclick").attr('onclick','check();');

Answer (score 0):

Just try,

```
$("#disableclick").removeAttr('onclick');
```

instead of

```
$("#disableclick").removeAttr('click');
```

Comment: @SomnathKharat Yeah, it was a typo.

Comment: can you do a demo in jsfiddler please...it's not working

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: what could be the syntax to add back click event again

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy $("#disableclick").attr('onclick','check();');

Comment: if I want to enable the onclick without any function name ?